# Recompile and reinstalling php

Tags: php, fedora, recompile

I am running Fedora Core 10 with php 5.2.9 without ldap. Now i want to remove current php installation and recompile the latest version of php with ldap and install it.

How to do this?

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with Fedora and therefore can't provide a step by step solution this is only a comment, not an answer: Use the build system of the distribution, copy the existing rule file, modify it and build a new php package (or multiple). Otherwise (if you compile php "manually") the next update by the packet manager _might_ remove your changes. see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji

Answer (score 1):

Basically, download the sources from the PHP website. Then, from a terminal, type './configure --prefix=/usr/local/my_php_version'
In the output, checks if it recognize your LDAP installation (and also the Apache one). If not, take a look at the configuration options to learn how to specify the paths. Something like '--with-openldap', '--with apxs', etc.
You should also take a look at the configuration options to active the features you need.
Once you're done, type 'make', then 'sudo make install'.
Also take a look at the official install documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-compiling the PHP, you can add the LDAP support to the PHP you have installed.

You can install a variety of libraries and modules without recompiling PHP. To see the libraries that are available, you can execute

```
  yum search php-
```

To install LDAP for your PHP, you can execute

```
  yum install php-ldap
```

If you have PHP as an Apache module, you must restart the `httpd` to activate the changes

```
  service httpd restart
```